# Call a script from another script Python3

Tags: python-3.x, shell, opencv, argparse, ubuntu-18.04

I have 1 script that uses openCV to recognize a face in an image which inn the end it displays it via cv2.imshow

the script uses `argparse` to call several arguments into it:
`python3 recognize.py --x x --y y --z z`

I wanted to keep calling that same script on itself, using `subprocess.call(python3 recognize.py --x x --y y --z z', shell = True)` the image won't disappear once displayed

`cv2.waitKey(0)` and other variations(press X key to close windows, and `cv2.deleteAllWindows()`) doesn't do the trick either

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution, by puttig the code in a `def main():` and calling the script outside it, now the window from cv2 closes without any problem

```
def main():
     #code here
     cv2.imshow("img", img)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
     cv2.destroyAllWindows()
if __name__ == "__main__"
     main()
subprocess.call('python3 recognize.py --x x --y y --z z', shell = True)
```